# How to list SD card folders and files folders and files programmatically

Tags: android

I'm a newbie in android.
I got an application in which I had list all SD files and folders which include doc,pdf,xls,jpg etc.

How to get Folder Name and File Name of all Folders and files present in my SD card programmatically in android?

I'm using this code but unable to get folder name(root folders and sub folders).

```
String pdfPattern = ".pdf";         
File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
  if (listFile != null) 
       {
         for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) 

          {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) 
              {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
              }
            else 
              {
            if(listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pdfPattern))
                   {
                  //Do what ever u want                                                                                                         mArrayList.add(listFile[i].getName());
                       Log.v("", "---------             "+listFile[i].getName());
            }
        }
        }
ArrayAdapter songList = new ArrayAdapterthis,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mArrayList);
mlistview.setAdapter(songList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this [sample file explorer](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html).

And this is the method that traverses through the sdcard to fetch the list of files and directories.

```
private void getDir(String dirPath)

{

 myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);



 item = new ArrayList<String>();

 path = new ArrayList<String>();



 File f = new File(dirPath);

 File[] files = f.listFiles();



 if(!dirPath.equals(root))

 {



  item.add(root);

  path.add(root);



  item.add("../");

  path.add(f.getParent());



 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you tell me how to get only folder name and how many folder are present in SD card with folder name. This is the task I want to do.

Comment: What about searching in them? via file name?